# Conditional Formatting TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am getting an usual error when trying to apply a format using a conditional format and I am unsure what would be causing it. Specifically, the issue seems to be caused by attempting to apply the second conditional formatting in the elif statement.

Here is the code that is causing the issue:

```
for key in dfDiff.index:
        if not(key in df_OLD.index):
          if (key in df_NEW.index):
            worksheet.conditional_format((dfDiff.index.get_loc(key)+1), 0, (dfDiff.index.get_loc(key)+1), 0, {'type': 'unique',
                                                                                                              'format': new_fmt})
        elif(key in df_NEW.index):
            worksheet.conditional_format((dfDiff.index.get_loc(key)+1), 0, (dfDiff.index.get_loc(key)+1), 0, {'type': 'unique',
                                                                                                              'format': removed_fmt})
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adam\Scripting\xlxsComparer.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\adam\Scripting\xlxsComparer.py", line 156, in main
    excel_diff(path_OLD, path_NEW, index_col)
  File "C:\Users\adam\Scripting\xlxsComparer.py", line 130, in excel_diff
    'format': removed_fmt})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 83, in cell_wrapper
    int(args[0])
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Without looking too closely at your code the error is saying that `args[0]` is an array with more than one element/item so it cannot be converted to an `int` (scalar). And this is causing the error -  `'format': removed_fmt}`. One of your arguments for `worksheet.conditional_format(..)` in the elif clause is wrong - it is probably looking for an int or single item array and you are passing it a multiple value array.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)